Do I have to apply for a new US Visa when I change nationalities?
I recently changed my nationality from Indian to Jamaican and obtained a new passport. The US Visa on my Old Indian passport has not expired yet.
I saw online that you can present both old and new passports when travelling if your US visa has not expired, only if the passports are issued from the same country. Since I changed my nationality, this is not the case.
So, should I apply for a new visa? Or can I just present both passports at the airport?

You acquired the Jamaican nationality, but did you renounce or lose the Indian nationality in the process?

@jcaron India has a fairly strict statutory regime for the prevention of multiple nationality that provides for automatic loss of Indian nationality on acquisition of any other.  No renunciation is necessary for this to happen.

Do you have any reason to doubt what you read online?  The answer to your question is clear from the source you describe; why are you asking here?  Do you worry that you misunderstood it or that it is disreputable?


I saw online that you can present both old and new passports when travelling if your US visa has not expired, only if the passports are issued from the same country.

That is correct. See here:

If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country


So, should I apply for a new visa?

Yes.

Indian citizenship Act does not provide for dual citizenship.  Under Section 12(1A) of the Passports Act, possession of Indian passport by foreign nationals is cognizable offence. This equally applies to Indian nationals who have acquired foreign citizenship. Those who acquired foreign nationality are required to surrender passport.
Link: https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/passports_act.pdf
https://www.hcilondon.gov.in/page/surrender-of-indian-passport/

This does not answer the question, OP did not indicate keeping the Indian Nationality but keeping the passport invalidated, as happens when you get a new passport of the same country.

@Willeke the question does not say that the Indian passport was invalidated.  Regardless of whether this answers the question, it is important information that the asker should know.  (I am also under the impression that India doesn't return invalidated passports to its former citizens, but I am not certain of that.)

@phoog, important information, yes, answering the question, no.

By this answer "possession of Indian passport by foreign nationals is cognizable offence",  I meant OP cannot present his Indian passport anywhere for his travel purpose, as it is no longer valid.

@RohithKD, if a passport is replaced by a new passport of the same country and invalidated it is also no longer valid and can not be used on its own. Visa in it can still be valid. OP asked if in this case the visa in the (now invalid) Indian passport would still be accepted by the US. Which is answered in the other answer but ignored in your answer. (It will no be accepted, according to the other answer which should also be part of your answer.)
